# How can I run the equivalent of Excel's GAMMALN function in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, math

Excel has a GAMMALN function that returns the natural logarithm of the gamma function, Γ(x).

Such that, GAMMALN(4) returns the Natural logarithm of the gamma function at 4, yielding
1.7917595.

Postgres doesn't seem to have a GAMMALN equivalent function that I can tell. How can I go about calculating this?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to:

- create
  [Pl/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) extension
- install [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html)
- use [the function.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaln.html)

Comment: This is less fun, but probably more practical than rolling one's own implementation. Also one would get all the other functions too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to reimplement the log-gamma function since Postgres doesn't have it. How much trouble that will be depends on how general you want it to be. If you only need log-gamma for integers, then you can make use of the definition

```
log(gamma(n)) = log((n - 1) times (n - 2) times (n - 3) times ... times 1)
```

which is therefore `log(n - 1) + log(n - 2) + log(n - 3) + ... + 0`. I'm assuming one can express that in SQL, although I don't know how to do the summation.

For nonintegers, you have choices to make. A casual web search finds [this article about implementing log-gamma in C#](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/the-log-gamma-function-with-c/), from which you can get some ideas and references. A simplistic approach which could be acceptable if you don't need much precision is to do the descending product `log(x - 1) + log(x - 2) + log(x - 3) + ...` and then find a simple approximation (maybe just a lookup table) for the final `log(gamma(x - floor(x) + 1))` (I mean, a simple approximation for gamma(x - floor(x) + 1) and then take the log of that).

Take a look at Abramowitz & Stegun and its latter-day counterpart, the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions. Both are on the web.

Good luck and have fun, looks like an interesting problem.